# WebBrowserTask for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: .net, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I may sound like a noob, but this problem is really not getting out of my mind, you should try it too.

whenever i add Microsoft.Phone.dll to a new project of Windows Phone 8.1 for the WebBrowserTask control, i get the following error.

And i have really no idea how to solve this.

[http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-esfQ3c5cZ80/U2KBD5JRDyI/AAAAAAAAAiQ/HyorukOc_a4/s1600/Screenshot+(6).png](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-esfQ3c5cZ80/U2KBD5JRDyI/AAAAAAAAAiQ/HyorukOc_a4/s1600/Screenshot+%286%29.png)

In previous versions (Windows Phone 8) it is fully functioning, but as we all know there are many changes in the WP8.1 SDK, therefore, i am not able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Windows store apps project (WP8.1/Win8.1), WebBrowserTask class was replaced by [Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx) class.

Now you must use [LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) method from Launcher class

***Some useful resources :***

[What's New in Windows Phone 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn632424.aspx)

[Migrating your Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Runtime XAML app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: ahhh, i was too thinking Microsoft would have done something like this to irritate us. 

Can you please share a link having all these small changes to the new SDK. :)

Comment: I've just added few useful links

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string uriToLaunch = @"http://www.bing.com";
    var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
    var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);              
}
```

Don't forgot to use "async" keyword to Button_Click method